# Using a Model Class of Type T or Interface for Strongly Typed View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to refactor a view and model.  Previously, the strongly typed view had this model directive in the CSHTML file:

```
@model MyViewModel<MySubViewModel>
```

I've since identified that the type MySubViewModel needs to be either generic or inheritable because I've identified multiple types that should be interchangeable here.

First I tried this:

```
@model MyViewModel<T>
```

... which I couldn't make work, so, wishfully thinking, I tried this:

```
@model MyViewModel<T> where T : IMySubViewModel
```

... that's no good either, so I finally tried this:

```
@model MyViewModel<IMySubViewModel>
```

... at first I thought that was working as Visual Studio didn't underline it.  However, I quickly saw that every place I have a Razor insertion, it's showing as an error with the message "The name 'Whatever' does not exist in the current context."  This goes for the ViewBag, Html helpers and all usages of my view model.

So how should this be done?  Or can it not be done?  I realize I could probably use:

```
@model MyViewModel<dynamic>
```

... but I'd rather not lose the Intellisense given that I know the "dynamic" type will always be something that implements IMySubViewModel.

Comment: What namespaces are MyViewModel and IMySubViewModel from?

Comment: I am supprised that `@model MyViewModel<IMySubViewModel>` did not work. I assume that `MyViewModel` is defined as a generic type and that there is no restriction on the type that would prevent interface `IMySubViewModel` from being used as the generic type argument?

Comment: @Jakotheshadows - They're in namespaces specific to the solution, but there seems to be no issue with the types not being recognized.

Comment: @Igor - Good thought.  The definition of MyViewModel is this:

public class MyViewModel<T> where T : IMySubViewModel

Comment: does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735903/using-a-generic-model-in-asp-net-mvc-razor

Comment: @Igor - Interestingly, the answer at the bottom of the page (with 18 upvotes) is suggesting to do exactly what I've done.  I wonder why it's not working?

Comment: @bubbleking see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319189/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-studio-2015? you didn't mention anything in your answer about having tried the component cache, so I would give that a try just in case.

Comment: @Jakotheshadows - That component cache trick did it!

Comment: I have a feeling you're going down a difficult road which there are numerous alternatives to that are easier to program and easier to maintain.  Is this single view going to use properties of the Generic class and the Generic type class?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Thanks for the concern. The view is not actually using members of the generic type class, only the generic class. I got it working as MyViewModel<IMySubViewModel>. The view only uses MyViewModel properties and merely makes the IMySubViewModel available to JavaScript (we basically dump its contents into Knockout templates).

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to these questions:

[Why can't my view's model bind with my generic ViewModel which implements an interface? (ASP.NET MVC 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5762302/234132)
[Pass subclass of generic model to razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646812/234132)

So, drawing from those, you need to introduce an interface with a covariant generic type parameter:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WcIzrr

Answer (score 0):

> The view is not actually using members of the generic type class, only the generic class. I got it working as MyViewModel. The view only uses MyViewModel properties and merely makes the IMySubViewModel available to JavaScript (we basically dump its contents into Knockout templates).

If there is no advantage to using Generics in this instance, then I would suspect you can easily use this as an alternative:

```
public MyViewModel
{
  public Object KoTempModels { get; set; }
}
```

And simply populate the `KoTempModels` property with the model(s) you need.